# Write-in developer types

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

The list of developer types is woefully incomplete. Please allow people to write in their own, or expand the list.

Examples of missing types: UI engineer, server dev (not web), DB optimization, DB engineer, data scientist

Comment: You should be more detailed. What types are you expecting to see that aren't there?

Comment: "Code Monkey", or [how about "Software Simian"](http://dilbert.com/strip/2008-03-04)?